# Whats wrong with setInterval() and clearInterval() in this javascript function? clearInterval returns undefined

Tags: javascript, timer

I have the following code:

```
var focusIntervalObj = setInterval(function(){
            focusDelayCaused++;
            console.log(focusDelayCaused);
        }, 100);

clearInterval(focusIntervalObj);
```

I am have a firebug installed.

I am expecting this code to log the value of `focusDelayCaused`.

But when I execute, it doesn't do so, and also the `clearInterval()` simply returns undefined.

Please guide.

Comment: What's the wider context? Can you post some more code?

Comment: Where have you defined `focusDelayCaused`? As it is right now, that's an undeclared variable.

Comment: Mark B, yep I got it, its undeclared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the interval and clearing it before it fires.

```
var focusIntervalObj = setInterval(function(){
        focusDelayCaused++;
        console.log(focusDelayCaused);
        clearInterval(focusIntervalObj);
    }, 100);
```

That might be what you are thinking. Which would be simpler as:

```
var focusIntervalObj = setTimeout(function(){
        focusDelayCaused++;
        console.log(focusDelayCaused);
    }, 100);
```

Comment: That makes sense, But I am using the `setInterval()` in some `blur` event, and the `clearInterval()` in a `focus` event. However, your's answer makes me look into the problem more clearly. thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Going on the code above, you're immediately clearing an interval just after you've set it. So it never has a chance to run.

Clearing the interval after some sort of condition has been met rather than immediately after setting it would help.

```
if (focusDelayCaused>50) {
  clearInterval(focusIntervalObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some function be executed once and never again, use setTimeout, in your case:

```
var focusIntervalObj = setTimeout(function(){
            focusDelayCaused++;
            console.log(focusDelayCaused);
        }, 100);
```

Comment: I want it to be executed constantly at some intervals and that's why I have used it.

Comment: The clearInterval function stops a "timer" (setInterval handler)